# iOS 11 Tab Bar items are offset

Tags: ios, ios11, xcode9

After upgrading to Xcode 9 and building my app for iOS 11, I have had a problem with the positioning of items in the `UITabBar`. They are offset to the left (shown in red outline).

[image: UITabBar items offset, shown in red outline.]

I am using just a regular `UITabBarController` and have not done any custom UI code. I've tried looking for any new `UITabBar` properties that would effect this, but I can't find anything. Messing with `UITabBar` `itemPositioning` property doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: make sure that you have only one viewController in your tabBarViewController.viewcontrollers array

Comment: No matter how many items are in the tab bar (view controllers added to the tab bar view controller), the items are offset.